# POST arbitrary text with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, http, http-post, afnetworking

I have seen how you can POST urlencoded forms and json using HttpClient.

But how do I POST arbitrary text?

My use case is that I already have my JSON string created, so I want to post the string directly, instead of constructing a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `HTTPBody` property on `NSMutableURLRequest`, and use anywhere in AFNetworking that takes an `NSURLRequest` parameter.